# Matlab : On filter() function behaving differently

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing, moving-average

I want to implement a Moving AVerage model of lag 2 whose functional form is :

```
 y[n] = h1*x[n] + h2*x[n-1] + h3*x[n-2]
```

having coefficients, `h_true = [h1, h2, h3]`;

The output is a scalar valued number at `n`.
Matlab has `filter()` function which can be used to implement a MA or AR model. But, the output is different when I implemented the equation as it is and when using the `filter()` function. What is the correct way? Please find below the code.

```
N = 10;
x = rand(1,N);
h_true = [1, 0.6, 0.3]; %h1 = 1, h2 = 0.6; h3 = 0.3
y(1) = 0.0;
y(2) = 0.0;
for i =3 : N
       y(i) = h_true(1)*x(i) + h_true(2)*x(i-1) + h_true(3)*x(i-2);

    end

filtered_y = filter(h_true,1,x);
```

`y` and `filtered_y` is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While some of the terms do vanish for `i<3`, not all terms actually do. So as you compute `y`, you should still be accounting for those non vanishing terms:

```
y(1) = h_true(1)*x(1);
y(2) = h_true(1)*x(2) + h_true(2)*x(1);
for i =3 : N
  y(i) = h_true(1)*x(i) + h_true(2)*x(i-1) + h_true(3)*x(i-2);
end
```